Looking for a Japanese movie about roommates with antisocial behaviors living together
How I remember the plot and some characters: There's this group of roommates who exhibit anti social tendencies (e.g., there's this guy who breaks in into houses as soon as the homeowners leave their houses for the day), and right at the end of the movie, the guy who seemed to be "normal" turned out to be the serial killer who targets women. He was saved by his roommate from getting caught, and both returned to the apartment as though there's nothing unusual about being a killer. The last frame was that the camera was looking into a window where the killer guy was still on his knees, looking up to the calm and friendly faces of his roommates. 
Country: Japan
Setting: 21st century Japan
Genre: could be mystery, thriller or drama. I'm not sure
When did I see the movie: No idea. 
Where did I see the movie: It was running on Red HBO some years ago. 

A potential match is Party 7, which revolves around 7 characters in the same hotel room including a thief and a killer.
There is a trailer available on YouTube

Hello, the movie you provided looked interesting, but not what I'm looking for. The movie I'm pertainong to probably came out much later, probably around 2005 or above. And they all share the apartment where they get to interact with each other in the common spaces, watch the morning news together, etc.
